# Email Confirmation Token - UserManager.ConfirmEmail only works on page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity

I have a bit of a strange issue...I add new users to my system and they get sent an invite with a link they click to confirm acceptance and set a password.

I use the following to generate the token and URL sent in the email:

```
string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

code = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);

var callbackUrl = Url.Action("accept", "users", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

The email comes through fine and I click the link. On my 'accept' page I say:

```
code = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(code);

var result = UserManager.ConfirmEmail(userId, code);
```

Unfortunately, it always comes back with a fail on my live site (hosted on Azure App Services). Localhost seems to work. 
Even more strangely, when I refresh the live 'accept' page it then works?!

Has anyone come across this before? I hope so!

**Edit**
Delving deeper into this I have 2 things going on:

1. the fail seems to be down to 'userId' being null, even though I can see it in the URL? `var aspUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);`
2. when it does work (after refresh) I get an error on submission telling me the form is incomplete. (I ask the user to enter and confirm their password here - viewing the source shows me all the fields are filled in prior to submission).

Comment: *How* does it fail? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Hi Chris - I've updated

Comment: Post your controller action signature. Just because you passed an id in the URL doesn't necessarily mean it's making it into your action. Also, you should probably post the route that you're using to get to this action as well. If it's an attribute, include the attribute. Otherwise post the applicable line from your RouteConfig.cs.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I've found what it was - I was trying to work with the signed in user on the same request as the actual sign in itself. Instead I am now bouncing on to a new URL which ensures the signed in user is accessible for me.